# Android fires OutOfMemoryError while loading image from asmx web service

Tags: android, web-services, android-listview, android-studio, asmx

What can be cause for this error: 
     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 10111384 byte allocation with 1305618 free bytes and 1275KB until OOM

Error happens in this line :

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(currentTour.getTourImage(),0,currentTour.getTourImage().length);
```

My ListView adapter View :

```
  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null)
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tour_item, parent, false);
        if (position % 2 == 1) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(189, 230, 247));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }


        TourAnounceRow currentTour = tourAnounceList.get(position);

        if (currentTour != null) {
            TextView tourName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblTourName);
            tourName.setText(currentTour.getTourName());

            TextView place = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblPlace);
            place.setText(currentTour.getPlace());

            RatingBar tourStarCount = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarTourStarCount);
            tourStarCount.setRating(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(currentTour.getHotelStarsCount())));

            TextView adultCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblAdultCount);
            adultCount.setText(String.valueOf(currentTour.getAdultCount()));

            TextView childrenCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblChildCount);
            childrenCount.setText(String.valueOf(currentTour.getChildrenCount()));
            TextView mealCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblMealCount);
            mealCount.setText(String.valueOf(currentTour.getDailyMealCount()));

            TextView price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblPrice);
            price.setText(String.valueOf(currentTour.getPrice()));

            ImageView ivTourImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivTourImage);
            ivTourImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(currentTour.getTourImage(), 0,currentTour.getTourImage().length);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 10, stream);


            ivTourImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        }
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your bitmap it's to large, you can optimize the load of the bitmap, take a look to [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Thanks  f3rn4nd000 for help.

Comment: I changed my code    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(currentTour.getTourImage(), 0,currentTour.getTourImage().length);
                ivTourImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,120,120,false)); but my error also fired

Comment: You need first take the size of the real bitmap, using the bitmap options, then you calculate the correct size of the bitmap what you need, after that you gonna get the bitmap passing in the options, the required size of the bitmap, and then you don't get again the OOM exception

Comment: Yout solution not helped me. I changed my web service, before sending image i resized it.

Comment: That's probably the best solution if you have control over the server API, you will want to send scaled images as much as possible, especially if you're storing them all in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, especially since you're using this inside a ListView, that you take a look at the Glide Library (https://github.com/bumptech/glide). The library will handle both an asynchronous call to load the image, as well as the resizing of the image to fit your ImageView (saving memory).

You also seem to be hold a lot of byte[] images in memory (based on tourAnounceList), you want to only hold a reference to them when possible; either as a URL/URI or a local resource integer (R.drawable.my_image).

The code should look like this:

```
ImageView ivTourImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivTourImage);
Glide.with(parent.getContext()).load(currentTour.getImageUrl())
    .fitCenter().into(ivTourImage);
```